# jenkins slave runs as user

Tags: jenkins, permissions, active-directory

I have a jenkins setup with multiple users which are logging in with [Active Directory plugin](http://www.greenreedtech.com/jenkins-active-directory/). This is useful so that each user can access his own tasks.

However each user also has different permissions on the local network, such as access to different folders etc. I have noticed that the permissions given to each task is not linked to the user but to the account under which the slave is running as service. Is there a way to change that so that the task is executed on the slave under the credential (and hence permissions) of the user?

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

The problem is: there is only one slave process running the different job assigned to that server by the Jenkins master.
So the slave itself runs as one user (generally, a dedicated account or a system account).

Since you can get the user id as environment variable (with a plugin like [JENKINS Build User Vars Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+User+Vars+Plugin)), you might consider configuring the job in order for it build step to "run as" the user who triggered the build.
See for instance the [JENKINS Authorize Project plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Authorize+Project+plugin).

[image: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/download/attachments/70877566/authorize-project_01_globalsecurity.png?version=2&modificationDate=1439085782000&api=v2]

[image: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/download/attachments/70877566/authorization-page.png?version=1&modificationDate=1486871612000&api=v2]

However, as [mentioned this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41776176/6309):

> The "Authorize Project" plugin does not change the OS level user that is running commands.
>   It only sets the Jenkins user that is running the job and any downstream jobs, using Jenkins authentication (whatever it might be).

So you are left with [build step with runas or su -c commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24674229/6309) in order to be *sure* that your task does run with the right user.

Comment: For Windows runas, for instance, see http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/Error-running-Windows-batch-file-via-build-step-td4570615.html and the /savecred option.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar issue and I can recall for managing more control on projects I used [**role strategy plugin**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Role+Strategy+Plugin) and setup global security using LDAP servers (Active directory should also be ok).
And I used [**authorized project plugin**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Authorize+Project+plugin).
Have a look and I hope it should solve your purpose. Let me know on comment section for any clarification.

Comment: Unfortunately "Authorize-project plugin controls only authorizations of Jenkins, not those of OS."

Answer (score 1):

you can partially fix your problem this way:

- install the slave as a service using the Java Web Start method and JLNP
- go to Services control panel in windows
- under Properties -> Connection replace the local system connection with a specific user
- rebooted the service

This at least gives you the ability to use one account instead of system.

Comment: does this require having java installed on the target agent box?  trying to simply have my agent run as  an ssh session - but i think its trying to do so as a jenkins user as opposed t the user setup the agent to use